# Display image array based on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to accomplish the following....

1. Create a dropdown menu that is a list of last names
2. When a last name is selected, display all of the images with that last name

Attempt...

```html
<script>
    function displayAllImages() {
        var smith = ["text instead of Smith pictures","text instead of Smith pictures2"];
        var jones = ["text instead of Jones pictures"];

        for (i=0;i<2;i++) {
          document.write("<li><p>" + smith[i] + "<p/></li>");
        }
    };
</script>
<select>
  <option value="smith">Smith</option>
  <option value="jones">Jones</option>
</select> 
<div>
    <ul>
        <script>displayAllImages();</script>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What I need help with is relaying the dropdown selection to the the javascript function so I can switch between arrays.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you expecting to show all images that *match* the selected value or that *contain* the selected value?

Comment: Pro-tip: don't use `document.write`. [It will ruin your life.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

Comment: This is just a simple example, but I will have arrays of image paths, and when a dropdown is selected, that corresponding array name will display all of the elements

Comment: Can you post your real array of image paths?. We need to see the real issue that you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use on `change` event to capture the changes in you select and append the `li`s items to the target `ul` using the related array to the selected value.

**NOTE :** Using `window[string]` in the example bellow to get the variable name from `string` (selected option value).

---

```js
var smith = ["text instead of Smith pictures","text instead of Smith pictures2"];
var jones = ["text instead of Jones pictures"];

$('select').on('change', function(){
    $('ul').empty(); //reset ul
  
    var selected_array = window[$(this).val()];

    for (i=0;i<selected_array.length;i++) {
      $('ul').append("<li><p>" + selected_array[i] + "<p/></li>");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="smith">Smith</option>
  <option value="jones">Jones</option>
</select> 
<div>
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I can't get this to run locally or on JSFiddle, am I missing something? https://jsfiddle.net/exdu0572/

Comment: JsFiddle don't support `window[]` so it will not work ( you're missing also to include jquery library).

Comment: Would window[] work locally? what is the alternative

Comment: Thanks, eval works in jsfiddle, but im having trouble locally. I will mess around with it, thank you

Answer (score 2):

A different approach all in javascript can be:

```js
function displayAllImages(ele) {
  var smith = ["text instead of Smith pictures","text instead of Smith pictures2"];
  var jones = ["text instead of Jones pictures"];

  var obj = jones;
  var target = document.getElementsByClassName('target')[0];
  target.innerHTML = '';
  if (ele.selectedOptions[0].value == 'smith') {
    obj = smith;
  }
  obj.forEach(function(currValue, index, arr) {
    target.innerHTML += "<li><p>" + currValue + "</p></li>";
  });
};
window.onload = function(e) {
  displayAllImages(document.getElementById('selectBox'));
}
```

```html
<select id="selectBox" onchange="displayAllImages(this);">
    <option value="smith">Smith</option>
    <option value="jones">Jones</option>
</select>
<div>
    <ul class='target'>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arrAllImages = [];
arrAllImages["smith"] =
        [
            "http://www.letsgodigital.org/images/producten/3376/pictures/canon-eos-sample-photo.jpg",
            "http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6050/6287299751_395316b6cd_z.jpg",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/42/Sample-image.svg/703px-Sample-image.svg.png"
        ];
arrAllImages["jones"] =
        [
            "http://yesyoucanbuythat.com/store/resources/image/18/7a/f.png",
            "http://www.claridgeupholstery.com/images/samples/Beige.jpg",
            "http://www.quality-wars.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/gold_standard_main.jpg"
        ];
function displayUserImages() {
    $("li").remove();
    var strUserName = $("select").val();
    $.each(arrAllImages[strUserName], function () {
        $("<li><img src='" + this + "'/></li>").appendTo("ul");
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    displayUserImages();

    $("select").change(function () {
        displayUserImages();
    });
})
```

```css
li
{
    list-style: none ;
    display: inline
}
li img{
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <select>
        <option value="smith">Smith</option>
        <option value="jones">Jones</option>
    </select>
    <div>
        <ul></ul>
    </div>
</body>
```